# Why (1+3)[a] is the same as a[1+3]?

Tags: c++

While studying [18 Essential C++ Interview Questions](https://www.toptal.com/c-plus-plus/interview-questions), I found a question with the following (strange) statement:

```
std::cout << (1 + 3)[a] - a[0] + (a + 1)[2];
```

The answer then explained, `(1+3)[a] is the same as a[1+3]`, which is still strange for me.

May I ask for the history of this? Why it's so and how it helps to allow this?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I think this question should not be considered a duplicate of the linked question because it's about C++ and not C.

Comment: @Brian Feel free to vote for reopening.

Comment: No need from the looks of it. Looks like someone used the dupe anvil.

Comment: Yeah I just reopened it by myself. I was just leaving a comment to explain my reasoning

Comment: Wandering a smidgen off to the left a bit, but anyone know why C allows this? I grok the math, but grammatically it is a bit of a mindfreak. I always figured it was either for mathematical consistency or because the value of disallowing it was far less than the value of the added compiler complexity required to disallow it.

Comment: It allows it because there's no reason not to allow it. This is like asking why 2+1 should be 3 when 1+2 is also 3. The answer is because + means the same both ways, and that's the end of it. Why make a rule to ban it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In C, `a[i]` is defined to mean `*(a + i)`. Based on this definition you can see that `a[i]` and `i[a]` mean the same thing.

C++ inherited this "feature" from C, however, note that in C++:

- `i[a]` and `a[i]` only mean the same thing if they don't call overloaded operators; for example the code you posted will not work if `a` has type `std::vector<int>`.
- In C++14 and above, `a[i]` is not identical to `*(a + i)` since the former is not always an lvalue.

Comment: In which case in C++14 and above is a[i] not an lvalue? Just curious.

Comment: @AlexTelon a[i] is an [_xvalue_](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#xvalue) if a is an array _rvalue_. See also [built-in_subscript_operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_subscript_operator).